# How quickly could modern humans go through the techtree?

Tags: humans, technological-development

Let's say a few humans and among them 1-2 scientists from each field were to travel back in time before humans.

How fast could they get to modern technology under the assumption that they had enough reliant food sources or worker humans to not impede their progress in anyway?

Comment: This question already has an answer here: http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/41960/2746

Comment: @dot_Sp0T is not, this question excludes social issues, and focuses on tech only.

Comment: @MolbOrg than this should be made clearer. Shouldn't it? As of now the way this question is written all answers that could be wished for can be found in the linked question.

Comment: Most answer there revolve around the fact that you will mostly fight for survival. My question is about pre-human conditions, with no interference from local hostile humans trying to kill you and steal everything you have.

Comment: @dot_Sp0T I have checked answers again, all answers are focusing on influence and interaction with local population. Because it is what that question asks - boosting technological development of bronze age people. None of those answers are focusing on technological tree itself. I guess one who marked the question as duplicate of another one - have 0 technical background, and just ruined all fun for those who understand premise of this particular question, if not to answer it(because it to too broad actually) but to generate few useful ideas, how it may be done, if any one have such ideas.

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful try editing your question to make it less broad and make that more clear and I am sure it will be reopened in a jiffy